# String toTwoCompliments(byte n) -> Error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

Tags: java, binary, byte

I've written a method to turn a byte into a TwoCompliments string. But when i run the code, it shows:
incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

```
String toTwoCompliments(int n) {
  String binary = "";
  if(n < 0) {
    n = n * (-1) -  1;
    while(n != 0) {
      if(n % 2 == 0) {
      binary = "1" + binary;
      n /= 2;
      } else {
      binary = "0" + binary;
      n /= 2;
      }
    }
    while(binary.length() < 8) {
      binary = "1" + binary;
    }
    return binary;
  } else {
    while(n != 0) {
      binary = n % 2 + binary;
      n /= 2;
    }
    while(binary.length() < 8) {
      binary = "0" + binary;
    }
    return binary;
  }
}
```

If for example I run **toTwoCompliments(64)** it returns an error. Where is my mistake? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `System.out.println(toTwoCompliments(64));` prints `01000000` here; have you tried a clean build? Also, what was wrong with `Integer.toBinaryString(int)`?

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/nsq7pv). Voting to close as a non-reproducible error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I meant to have **byte** as parameter, so the correct code is

```
String toTwoCompliments(byte n) {
  String binary = "";
  if(n < 0) {
    n = n * (-1) -  1;
    while(n != 0) {
      if(n % 2 == 0) {
      binary = "1" + binary;
      n /= 2;
      } else {
      binary = "0" + binary;
      n /= 2;
      }
    }
    while(binary.length() < 8) {
      binary = "1" + binary;
    }
    return binary;
  } else {
    while(n != 0) {
      binary = n % 2 + binary;
      n /= 2;
    }
    while(binary.length() < 8) {
      binary = "0" + binary;
    }
    return binary;
  }
}
```

Comment: Since that's of no help to anyone else, please just delete the question.